# C++: How to change 'PCZZWSTR' type to 'char' or vice versa?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, copy, directory

In C++ in Visual Studio, I am trying to copy folders dynamically using a loop. For that, I used `sprintf` function to change the folders as follows:

```
char sourceName[1000];
char dstName[1000];
SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf;
memset(&sf, 0, sizeof(sf));
sf.hwnd = 0; 
sf.wFunc = FO_COPY;

for (int i=1; i<100; i++)
{
    sprintf(sourceName, "C://Samples//%d//",i);
    sprintf(dstName, "U://NewData//%d//",i);
    sf.pFrom = sourceName;
    sf.pTo = dstName;
}
```

But the line for sf.pFrom and sf.pTo give out error saying:

```
Error: a value of type "char*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type PCZZWSTR.
```

I tried changing the sourceName and dstName into PCZZWSTR type while declaring them:

```
PCZZWSTR sourceName;
PCZZWSTR dstName;
```

But this time the sprintf function doesn't accept them. So is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not using wide characters for a start. You also didn't double null terminate them.

Comment: @chris: I don't understand it fully. Could you please explain more in depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several issues in your code.

1. First of all, remove double slashes in file name `'//'`. It's required to double only backslashes as `'\'` is escape character.
2. Use [`wsprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `sprintf`. Use `wchar_t`s instead of `char`s.
3. Read what [SHFILEOPSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is. Its members `pFrom` and `pTo` are *one or more* file names. They must be double-null terminated.